# Linked string list C / Struct

Tags: c, string, function, struct, linked-list

I'm to create a LinkedList that has functionalities of adding and printing strings within.

Attaching my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Line {
       char tekst[20];
       struct Line *next;
};

void print(const struct Line* n);
void add(struct Line* n, char t[20], struct Line* next);

int main(void) {
    struct Line lin, *tekst;
    tekst = NULL;
    add(&lin, "ExampleString1", tekst);
    add(&lin, "ExampleString2", tekst);
    print(&lin);

    getch();
    return 0;  
};

void print(const struct Line* n) {
     for ( ; n; n = n->next )
         printf("%s", n->tekst);
     printf("\n");
}

void add(struct Line* n, char t[20], struct Line* next) {
     strcpy(n->tekst,t); // before: n->tekst[20] = t[20];
     n->next = next;
}
```

It writes some random numbers on the standard output, and then crashes the commandline.
I've no idea whether `tekst2[20]` should even be here (I'm not sure how to call my function arguments here).

My goal is to make a list of strings then be able to add and print them.

Comment: Related: You're passing an *indeterminate* pointer value as the `next` parameter to `add()`, thereby invoking **undefined behavior** when you evaluate that during your `print()` enumeration. Just in case you missed that. I.e. `tekst` in `main()` is uninitialized.

Comment: I did not miss that. I'm unaware of how to pass the right ``next`` value while calling my ``add()`` function. That's one of things I'm asking for to get help with ;)

Comment: For this specific code, you can address that issue by simply initializing `tekst` to NULL before sending it as the `next` value to `add()`. Honestly, however, this is rather odd for linked list insertion code to begin with. Normally the insertion takes a pointer-to-pointer for the list head, and there are *hundreds* of examples of this on SO.

Comment: As stated at the top of my question, it's the first time I'm writing anything alike, and anything at all in C. I don't want to stick to a wrong code, so as long as you are acknowledged with a fixing idea, it wouldn't hurt to share it with me.

Comment: Are new node insertions supposed to be on the *head* of the list? or the *end* of the list? it makes a difference in how the `add()` function is developed.

Comment: New insertions are supposed to be added accordingly with their sequence, meaning that whenever I insert a new string, it should be added after the prior.

The overall idea will be to implement this later on into a program, that will get the text from standard input, and then depending on some values add margins and make it 2 columns per line

But right now I need only linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm nearly certain this is what you're trying to do:

```
void add(struct Line** pp, const char *t)
{
    struct Line *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    strcpy(p->tekst, t);
    p->tekst2[0] = 0;
    p->next = NULL;

    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    *pp = p;
}
```

Your `print()` function is using the wrong format specifier for printing a string:

```
void print(const struct Line* n) 
{
     for ( ; n; n = n->next )
         printf("%s\n", n->tekst);
     printf("\n");
}
```

Putting it together in `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct Line *lst = NULL;

    add(&lst, "SomeTxt");
    add(&lst, "SomeMoreTxt");
    add(&lst, "YetMoreTxt");

    print(lst);

    getch();
    return 0;  
};
```

**Output**

```
SomeTxt
SomeMoreTxt
YetMoreTxt
```

I leave the proper list cleanup code as well as proper error checking as a task for you.

**How It Works**

This function utilizes a "pointer-to-pointer" idiom. When you pass `&lst` from `main()`, you're passing the *address* of a pointer variable. Pointers are nothing more than variables that *hold* addresses to stuff (of the type the pointer it declared, of course). Example:

```
int a;
int *b = &a;
```

declares a pointer-to-`int`, and assigns the *address* of an `int` to store within it. On the other hand, this:

```
int a;
int *b = &a;
int **c = &b;
```

declares what we had before, but `c` is declared to be a *pointer-to-pointer-to-int*. Just like we stored the address of an `int` in `b`, notice how we store the address of a `int*` in `c`. this is a *very* powerful feature of the language.

That said, the code works like this:

```
void add(struct Line** pp, const char *t)
{
    // node allocation stuff. nothing special here
    struct Line *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    strcpy(p->tekst, t);
    p->tekst2[0] = 0;
    p->next = NULL;

    // look at the pointer addressed by our pointer-to-pointer pp
    //  while it is not null, store the address of the `next` pointer 
    //  of that node in pp and loop.
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    // pp now holds the address of the pointer we want to set with our new node
    //  it could be the address of the original pointer passed in (if the list was
    //  empty). or the address of some `next` member in the list. We really don't 
    //  care which. All we care about it is it addresses the pointer we need to 
    //  assign our new allocation to, so that is what we do.
    *pp = p;
}
```

Spend some time on the net researching C and pointers to pointers. They will change the way you think about things like list management. The most important thing to remember is a pointer to pointer does *not* pointer to some "node"; it points to a *pointer* that points to a node. That is a pretty heady statement, but do some homework and it will make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Could you please explain to me, what's going on inside ``add()`` ? I also deleted ``tekst2[20]`` because there was no need for it. I don't get the ``struct Line** pp`` and the rest that uses it.

Comment: I believe your comment above line with ``while (*pp)`` was supposed to say ``while it is NOT null``

Comment: @nobodynoone heh. see? you *do* understand =P

Answer (score 0):

Edited:Use line below (or `strncpy`) `strcpy(n->tekst,t);` instead of  `n->tekst[20] = t[20];`

Initialize *test to null

```
struct Line lin, *tekst=NULL;
```

Use %s to print text in your program.

```
printf("%s", n->tekst);
```

Comment: I don't want to get the 21st element of the array. It's just that I thought this is how I represent a string with 20 bytes, since I cannot use "string" type. I don't really think you got my goal that I'd like to obtain

Comment: @nobodynoone answer edited as per your query. sorry for earlier answer.